# Is there a cross platform desktop framework that would utilize native libraries such at .NET and Cocoa?

Tags: graphics, cross-platform, desktop-application

I am starting a project that is heavily graphics related (think, paint app with layers).

Anyway, I have a long history in C#, Java, JavaScript and Ruby.  This application will be open source.

But what I'm looking for is a "build once, use everywhere" framework.  Most of the platforms I've looked into either seem to be far too outdated, too complicated, or just not a right fit.

I've looked into `Swing`, `WindowBuilder`, `wxRuby`, etc.  So many choices and none seem modern enough, have good documentation, etc.

I was a `C#` desktop developer for years so if I were targeting Windows only, I would go that route easily.  But I want my app to run on Macs too.  But, I would like the Mac version to look like it was designed for a Mac and the Windows version designed for Windows, etc.  I'm looking at the `Mono Project` currently.  But the idea of my Mac users installing Mono doesn't appeal to me.

Anything Ruby based would be cool but not required.

Anyway, what are some recommendations?  I use NetBeans, Eclipse and Visual Studio.  So I'm not concerned with learning new IDE's if I had to.  I even thought about doing it all in JavaScript and using the canvas but since I need to work with large, local binary files, I didn't know if that would be a good option.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Wow.  Down-vote already?  So, is it simply not allowed to ask for recommendations on SO?

Comment: As it is, there is no good way to answer your question which is why you are seeing negative feedback (downvote). The main Stackoverflow site is focussed on questions with a definite answer rather than questions that are subjective or poll-like. It is a perfectly good question for Programmers.Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: OK, I upvoted your comment because that makes sense.  I've often been confused on why there is SO and Programmers.SO.  So, SO (this one) is meant for more cut/dry bare facts.  Whereas Programmers.SO contains more subjective and opinionated questions and answers?  I see how this is beneficial but I'm so used to going to SO for my needs, it's hard to remember sometimes.  However, while I did ask for recommendations, the question itself is not subjective to opinion. Technically, a "YES" could be a true answer.  Removing the last paragraph from my question would render it fact based. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com) can create cross-platform desktop apps for OS X, Windows and Linux. It can also create Cocoa apps and you can use it to interface with Cocoa directly when needed.

However, Real Studio creates Win32 apps, not .NET apps so you cannot directly interface with .NET libraries.

Comment: Maybe this will help someone out.  I went ahead and bought the $100 personal edition of `Real Studio`.  While you have to purchase a license for each platform (Windows, Mac, Linux) at $100 each, I mainly needed Mac at the moment.  And, there is going to be a pricing change this year so I will be grandfathered in when that happens and get all three platforms for my original $100 fee.  I found spending $100 on something that works very well (no complicated or deprecated libraries to deal with) was well worth it.  And no, I'm not affiliated with Real Studio.  Downside is the lack of SSL support.

Comment: FYI, the Professional and Enterprise editions support multiple platforms and have SSL support (among many other things). (Note: I am affiliated with Real Software).